# Squirrel SQL Error occcured initialising plugin

Tags: windows-10, sql

Suddenly out of the blue without knowingly changing anything I got the errors:

```
Error occurred initializing plugin: oracle

java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid input: ` (0x0),
SystemID='file:.', Line=1
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.plugins.oracle.OraclePlugin.initialize(OraclePlugin    .java:336)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.plugin.PluginManager.initializePlugins(PluginManager.java:575)


Error occurred initializing plugin: codecompletion

java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid input: ` (0x0),
SystemID='file:.', Line=1
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.plugins.codecompletion.CodeCompletionPlugin.loadPrefs(CodeCompletionPlugin.java:209)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.plugins.codecompletion.CodeCompletionPlugin.initialize(CodeCompletionPlugin.java:162)
```

and so on for other plugins resulting in a failed startup under Windows 10.

A fresh install did not help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution followed this [suggestion from the authors to remove the relevant config files](https://sourceforge.net/p/squirrel-sql/bugs/1044/) *for each failing plugin in my case* in the subfolders under

```
C:\Users\[USERNAME]\.squirrel-sql\plugins
```

Apparently it doesn't like an empty file or a null/EOF character encoded in a particular way.